# Tinymce 4+ not applying style to span tag

Tags: html, css, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce for content designing but having issue while applying colors to text. It was working before but suddenly it stopped working so I debugged and found it was due to following code written for  tag:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'span',
```

I used it because except this it was not allowing me to add classes for it but now it's not applying style to text inside it. Any solution for implementing both of these requirements together? My complete code is as below:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea:not(.mceNoEditor)",
extended_valid_elements: 'span',
browser_spellcheck: true,
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
forced_root_block: '',
font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;AkrutiKndPadmini=Akpdmi-n;Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;',
fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt',
plugins: ["textcolor", "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor", "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen", "insertdatetime media table paste"],
toolbar: "fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
height: "200",
content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
],
image_title: true,
// enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
automatic_uploads: true,
// URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
images_upload_url: '../postAcceptor',
//    images_upload_base_path: 'http://localhost/colorin',
// here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
file_picker_types: 'image',
// and here's our custom image picker
file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
    // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
    // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
    // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
    // once you do not need it anymore.

    input.onchange = function () {
        var file = this.files[0];

        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name});
    };

    input.click();
}
});
```

Comment: Did you find the issue. Same for me when I save the code sample and get `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` it does not save the css classes like `token ...` and then code is not colored